# Send push-notification from Android to iOS and vice versa?

Tags: android, ios, push

I've just learned that its going to be pretty tough for me to realize an app that can send a push notification to another device, BUT: is it even worse to send it from **Android** to **iOS** respectively **iOS** to **Android** ? I know it's possible because `WhatsApp` does it, but okay, WhatsApp... 
The way I need it is, on Phone A `(Android)` a user clicks on a button "Send 'ring'" to user B `(iOS)`. 
When A clicks that Button, an `AlertDialog` `(UIAlertView)` shall appear on user B's screen. 
That's just to describe what I want to do, it obviously won't only send a 'ring'.

Any suggestions or good tutorials?

Comment: I'm not particular sure but I think you don't really send it to a certain device, but you send it to a server and in your app you build in a service that regularly checks for requests.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you need to implements the server-side logic, but everithing it's much simple if you use some services like [Parse](https://parse.com/products/push)

Here the docs related to [iOS](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/iOS) and [Android](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android).

They have their SDK, there is a pretty good documentation, you can setup everything very quickly. We are using Parse a lot recently and (specially for notifications) it's very helpful.

There are others services like this (most of them based on node.js):

[Deployd](http://deployd.com/) Open Source
  [Sockethub](http://sockethub.org/) Open Source

Comment: thank you for your help, much appreciated! can you do me a favor and describe a little more in detail what this is? Is parse like a server that does most of the work for me? How does it work, schematically?

Comment: if you look (se my edit) at the links, it's really simple. I added also some links about open source alternatives. Hope this will help you.